# "CleverTap" Can't see "Event Property" filter in Filter by event property in some events

Tags: android, clevertap

Right now , I am sending 10 events with 1 property each. But when i want to filter a particular event and select event by property then in "Event Property" filter shown in only first 7 event that i have added for rest of events only show "First Time" filter , why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do make sure that your properties for the other events aren't getting rejected. Do check the live error stream which is available from the top nav. You could  also check whether you've not accidentally discarded the properties in question.